# Logic Dots Problems with SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog, logic

I am currently working with Logic Dots Game Solver with SWI-prolog. The Logic Dots is kind of like Kakuro. There are numbers surrounding grid and the sum of each Row and Column must equal to that corresponding number. I searched on google but can not find out any sources with SWI prolog for this problem. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I just know that the constraint programming algorithm is easy to implement. But how to handle this in swi prolog?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logic Dots puzzle problems with SWI-Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270558/logic-dots-puzzle-problems-with-swi-prolog)