# Logic Dots puzzle problems with SWI-Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic, clpfd

I am working on a logic game named "Logic Dots". The game is a 3*3 grid with numbers surrounding each row and column. The rule is easy that the sum of each row and column should equal to those numbers. Below is my code, it is changed from clpfd sokoku. But result is something wrong.

Code:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

kakuro(Rows) :-
    length(Rows, 3), maplist(length_list(3), Rows),
    append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 0..1,
    Rows = [A,B,C],
    sum(A,#=,1),
    sum(B,#=,1),
    sum(C,#=,1),
    transpose(Rows, Columns),
    append(Columns, V), V ins 0..1,
    Columns = [D,E,F],
    sum(D,#=,1),
    sum(E,#=,1),
    sum(F,#=,1),
    Rows = [A,B,C].     

length_list(L,Ls) :- length(Ls,L).

problem([1,0,0,1,0,0], [[_,_,_],
                        [_,_,_],
                        [_,_,_]]).
```

Result:

```
?- problem([1,0,0,1,0,0], Rows), kakuro(Rows), maplist(writeln, Rows).
[_G670,_G673,_G676]
[_G682,_G685,_G688]
[_G694,_G697,_G700]
Rows = [[_G4520, _G4523, _G4526], [_G4532, _G4535, _G4538], [_G4544, _G4547, _G4550]],
_G4520 in 0..1,
_G4520+_G4532+_G4544#=1,
_G4520+_G4523+_G4526#=1,
_G4532 in 0..1,
_G4532+_G4535+_G4538#=1,
_G4535 in 0..1,
_G4523+_G4535+_G4547#=1,
_G4523 in 0..1,
_G4526 in 0..1,
_G4526+_G4538+_G4550#=1,
_G4538 in 0..1,
_G4550 in 0..1,
_G4544+_G4547+_G4550#=1,
_G4544 in 0..1,
_G4547 in 0..1.
```

But when I replace my puzzle with `[[_,0,0],[0,_,0],[0,0,_]]`, the result is correct:

```
?- problem([1,0,0,1,0,0], Rows), kakuro(Rows), maplist(writeln, Rows).
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
Rows = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]].
```

But I need grid to be unknown (symbol "_"). Where is the mistake?

I changed Rows = [A,B,C] of last line in `kakuro/1` to `label(Vs)`. It works, but only one result shows:

```
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
```

There should be another:

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[0,0,1]
```

What is wrong with it here?

Comment: dont bother with the first parameter of problem function :).

Comment: Replace Rows[A,B,C] with label(Vs) as last line of predicate kakuro/1 and try kakuro(Rows) at prompt.

Comment: It works. But there is only one result, there should be two results for my puzzle, why does it not show them?

Comment: You will get all the answers if you press Space instead of Enter at the prompt after the first solution

Comment: @user3889372, hi, do you still have the prolog program? could you please send me a copy of the .pl file at cguo@upei.ca. Thanks